# How to pass two arguments of custom type in spring controller using request body and method PUT

Tags: json, spring, rest, postman

Here users pass to the method normally:

```
@PutMapping
    @RequestMapping("/update_user")
    public String update(@RequestBody List<CustomUser>users) {
        return ......
    }
```

Postman PUT request body:

```
    [
    {"name":"Name1"},
    {"name":"Name2"}
    ]
```

---

But here I receive an error: "Failed to resolve argument 1 of type CustomUser":

```
@PutMapping
    @RequestMapping("/update_user")
    public String update(@RequestBody CustomUser user1, CustomUser user2) {
        return ......
    }
```

Postman PUT request body:

```
    {
    "user1":{"name":"Name1"},
    "user2":{"name":"Name2"}
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the `CustomUser` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> RequestBody annotated parameter is expected to hold the entire body of the request and bind to one object, so you essentially will have to go with one object only

Now, Either you can wrap them both like this

```
public class Payload {
    CustomUser user1;
    CustomUser user2;
    
    //getters & setters
}
```

and use that for `RequestBody`

```
@PostMapping
@RequestMapping("/update_user")
public String update(@RequestBody Payload users) {
    return ......
}
```

Or you can use a `Map<String, CustomUser>` for `RequestBody`

```
@PostMapping
@RequestMapping("/update_user")
public String update(@RequestBody Map<String, CustomUser> users) {
    //you can access like this
    
    CustomUser user1 = users.get("user1");
    CustomUser user2 = users.get("user2");
}
```

Another thing to note, you are mapping as `POST` request but your comment says "PUT". check that as well.

Comment: I made a mistake in the start topic, of course I do PutMapping

Comment: Next time I need to pass two arguments of different types, and map will no longer help. I know for sure that it is possible to pass two parameters of different custom types, but I don't understand what the error is

Comment: Yes, this is of course a possible way - to make the wrapper class, but I don't think this way is optimal - to make an extra class just to get around this problem

Comment: `@RequestBody` annotated parameter is expected to hold the entire body of the request and bind to one object, so you essentially will have to go with one object only. regarding your error, can you update stack trace for exception.

Comment: I didn’t think about it, thank you very much. Indeed, I was mistaken in the previous comment, I put a custom object in the body, but it was one object, not two. Thus, it turns out that it is in no way possible to pass two object-arguments in the body?

Comment: =@RequestBody annotated parameter is expected to hold the entire body of the request and bind to one object, so you essentially will have to go with one object only.=  Actually, this is the answer to my question: two parameters in the body cannot be passed